# Image/scene recognition

Tags: iphone, ios, image, sdk, image-recognition

Hi guys I'm looking for a solution to that enable a user compare a image to a previously store image. For example, i take a picture on my iPhone of a chair and then it will compare to a locally store image, if the similarity is reasonable then it confirms the image and calls another action.

Most solutions I've been able to find require cloud processing on third party servers(Visioniq, moodstocks, kooaba etc). Is this because the iPhone doesn't have sufficient processing power to complete this task?

A small reference library will be stored on the device and referenced when needed.
Users will be able to index their own pictures for recognition.

Is there any such solution that anyone has heard of? My searches have only shown cloud solutions from the above mentioned BaaS providers.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards,
Frank

Comment: [Moodstocks](http://www.moodstocks.com/) provides on-device image recognition: in practice image signatures are synchronized to the mobile device, and the algorithms run on the device as well. In other words the iPhone has enough processing power to do so. That being said Moodstocks does not support similarity search but only image matching, i.e given a camera frame it retrieves the ID of the exact match (if any) within a database of reference images while being invariant to common noises.

Comment: Thanks deltheil, I've already contacted them, hope they can help.

Comment: @frank - You may wish to check deltheil's profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try using OpenCV library in iOS

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

Comment: Thanks Mihir, currently looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using FlannBasedMatcher to match images. Documentation and code is available here You can see "[Feature Matching FLANN](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#feature-flann-matcher)" here.